# Controls like checkboxes and radio buttons are invisible : After Upgrade to 14.10

Tags: unity, desktop-environments, 14.10

I recently upgraded to 14.10 from 14.04. No matter what theme I try, radio buttons and checkboxes simply do not appear in my applications.

Any ideas?

Here's a [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PGQL.png) showing this:

[image]